# Express.js, I get colon in front of the value if my parameter value contains colon somewhere in a value

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

This is my simple express.js code, and GET routing:

```
app.get(path + hashKeyPath, function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    data: JSON.stringify(req.params.CognitoIdentity),
    dekor: JSON.stringify(
      req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId
    ),
  });
```

```
const path = '/address';
const partitionKeyName = 'CognitoIdentity';
const hashKeyPath = '/:' + partitionKeyName;
```

now when I send a request, my parameter can contain colon inside of the string (aws cognito identity is built like that not sure why would they put colon inside instead of dash but ok):
`eu-west-1:ea6b2959-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0` which returns only colon back in response.

```
config: {url: 'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws…s/:eu-west-1:ea6b2959-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0', method: 'get', data: null, headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
```

data: {data: ':eu-west-1:ea6b2959-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0', dekor: 'null'}

how can I get real value which would be `eu-west-1:ea6b2959-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0` and not colon as first char `eu-west-1:ea6b2959-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0` when I have coon inside of parameter value? well I assume it is doing it because of colon after `eu-west-1`...

Edit:
So it seems like no matter what you pass it gets `:` in front lol, what??

```
config: {url: 'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/address/:kontono-test', method: 'get', data: null, headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: {data: ':kontono-test', dekor: 'null'}
```

Comment: I thought you asked this already around 8 hours ago?

Answer (score 1):

In your examples you are sending values with leading `:` in URL param:

`/:kontono-test`

`/:eu-west-1:ea6b2959-8718-42b9-b8b8-ce82e9d9e7a0`

Try calling these endpoints without `:` in front.
Express won't remove the leading `:` from param **value**, because that can be a valid part of it.

You don't have to add `:` in URL when you are using URL params. For example:
in `/address/:identity` `:identity` will be available under `req.params.identity`, and you call this endpoint like so:

`GET http://localhost:3000/address/foobar` -> `req.params.identity == 'foobar'`

`GET http://localhost:3000/address/:foobar` -> `req.params.identity == ':foobar'`

`GET http://localhost:3000/address/foo:bar:` -> `req.params.identity == 'foo:bar:'`

`GET http://localhost:3000/address/:foo:bar:` -> `req.params.identity == ':foo:bar:'`